# Unable to access the dictionary property from within a callback of the constructor

Tags: javascript, dictionary, typescript

I have created a dictionary and inserted values to it as shown below using https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections#a-sample-on-dictionary.

```
private subscribedTopicsDict = new collections.Dictionary<string, MyTopic>();
 this.subscribedTopicsDict.setValue(topic, myTopic);
```

When I print the value for the key "myTopic" immediately after setting, its gets printed. But when I call it inside a callback within the constructor, nothing is happening. No errors but nothing after the getValue line is getting executed. Below is how I am calling it.

```
constructor(url: string, mqttOptions: MqttOptions, messageReceivedCallBack: IMessageReceivedCallBack) {
    if (!_.isString(url) || _.isEmpty(mqttOptions || _.isEmpty(messageReceivedCallBack))) {
      throw new MyError('invalid url value');
    } else {
      this.client = mqtt.connect(url, mqttOptions);
      this.client.on('message', (topic: string, message: string) => {
        let myMessage: myMessage;
        let receivedTopic: myTopic;
        console.log('1.onMessageReceived called with topic : ' + topic);
        receivedTopic = this.subscribedTopicsDict.getValue(topic);
        console.log('2.received topic and dataTypeID' + receivedTopic.dataTypeID);
        myMessage = {
          myTopic: receivedTopic,
          payload: message
        };
        console.log('about to fire the callback');
        messageReceivedCallBack.onMessageReceived(myMessage);
      });
    }

  }
```

The second console log is not getting printed. I tried with default dictionary functionalities of type script and got the same behavior as well.

Comment: That's just a declaration. Surely there is some scope issue here. I even tried changing that function into an arrow function. Still didn't help. Can you see any obvious errors with "this" keyword on the dictionary?

Comment: Could it be that within the new scope `this` ends up referencing another object?

Comment: Yeah that is my doubt as well. If that's the case, how else can I access that dictionary from within?

Comment: You could try declaring `var self = this` and use self to test if it's a scoping issue.

Comment: I placed var self = this above the line " this.client.on(.." and called it self.dictionary. Still no luck man :(

Comment: What about `var getValue = this.subscribedTopicsDict.getValue.bind(this.subscribedTopicsDict)` then simply use `receivedTopic = getValue(topic)`... If that fails then I have no idea what the issue could be.

Comment: wow :D that fixed it! Thanks man! I still don't understand what's wrong with the code I posted

Comment: Oh okay it seems as though one of the objects is being replaced. Either `subscribedTopicsDict` or `getValue` (possibly in addition to a scoping issue with `this`). That simply grabs an exact instance of the method you're using and binds it to the object you would be calling it from. But either way I guess this sets you on the right path. Glad it worked.